# trafego simultaneo no asp classico

Tags: mysql, servidor, asp, iis

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou com um problema na empresa recentemente precisamos migrar uma aplicação de um servidor para outro para economizar tempo fizemos uma imagem do servidor e subimos no novo, alteramos o ip do novo e colocamos para rodar as aplicações todas em asp classico. Fizemos os testes tudo funcionando quando passamos para os usuarios utilizarem, quando 2 ou mais acessavam o painel administrativos o retorno da consulta esta voltando para ambos os usuarios, alem de subir informações de um site para o outro quando faz a inserção.

no servidor antigo não tinhamos esse problema alguem ja passou por algo assim?

segue a string de conexao utilizada

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=host;Option=16419;Stmt=;Database=base;Uid=usuario;Pwd=senha
```

Comment: Nunca passei por isso, porém, vocês já verificaram se as versões do MySql Server são iguais e se foram configurados de forma idênticas? quanto ao asp classic, vocês analisaram consulta por consulta(select) gerando resultado? Toda migração geram problemas inesperados, liste os erros atuais e crie uma listagem para aprendizado, assim nos próximos já saberão como resolver os erros repetidos. Verifique também as configurações de permissão do IIS, caso tenham mudado a versão do IIS é possível que seja um dos motivos.

Comment: Ola Wilson na fiz esses testes a solução foi refazer a imagem do servidor e resolveu o problema aparentemente pode ter sido alguma coisa na criação da primeira imagem que apresentou problema, obrigado pelas dicas vou utilizar para aprendizagem caso ocorra algo assim

Comment: Que bom parabéns, agradecemos seu retorno contendo a solução encontrada. valeu.